# Who made RxJS / ReactiveX?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm curious who started ReactiveX / RxJS?

Rx seems to be implemented in a lot of languages/platforms, I'm curious to what's the origins of it? Which project was first?

RxJS is used heavily in Angular web framework. Was there a company behind it like Microsoft, Netflix or Google?

Comment: If you wanna take a look @ `rxjs` repo, here it is: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs... plus some good references: https://rxjs.dev/resources | https://reactive.how/

Answer (score 9):

The concept of Reactive Programming was introduced by Microsoft , then the library was made by Netfilx. [Here](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/optimizing-the-netflix-api-5c9ac715cf19) you can read more about Netflix Rx journey

Comment: Wow, not sure why this question got down voted... I guess not much history buffs around here... 

Anyway I found this as well. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/interoperability/2012/11/06/ms-open-tech-open-sources-rx-reactive-extensions-a-cure-for-asynchronous-data-streams-in-cloud-programming/

If that blog post is correct, the first version of Rx was for .NET and it was originally introduced by Microsoft.

Comment: Rx* is just a product of Microsoft that they Open Sourced. The strange thing was that when I developed in Windows Phone it would be Obsolete because .NET has also its own functionality. I even did replace those Rx functions with .NET functions. It was not an integrated .NET Component. And now suddenly its a Hot Open Source thing because its used heavily in Angular. Looks like some kind of reincarnation :-)